# How to move GIT repository from Unfuddle to Bitbucket (including branches)?

Tags: git, bitbucket, unfuddle

I would like to move my GIT repositories from Unfuddle to Bitbucket (including all branches) ?

A script or a step-by-step guide would be appreciated.

Comment: this isn't a free bitbucket support site, did you do any research?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully this is quite simple on Bitbucket. You can go to https://bitbucket.org/repo/import and specify the url of your Unfuddle repo then input your username and password. Bitbucket will take care of the rest, including history and branches.